# CORS issue with Angular and Serverless project: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: python, angular, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm working on an Angular project that interacts with a serverless backend. When attempting to make a request from my Angular web application (running on http://localhost:3456) to my serverless API

CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.---' from origin 'http://localhost:3456' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How can I resolve this CORS issue and allow requests from my Angular app to the serverless backend?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you'd configure to server to allow your specific origin.  This should be avoided as it will loosen your security.  Instead, make sure the front-end is served from the same domain as the backend.  (Keep everything same domain.)  If this is only for testing locally, you can launch a browser with CORS rules turned off.  (--disable-web-security flag on Chrome, you can set a profile for that)